# Зачем усложнять импорт в джава?

Tags: java, импорт

Ведь можно написать `import java.util.*`, зачем тогда писать `import java.util.Scanner`? Ведь полный импорт занимает меньше памяти и функциональнее.

Comment: Вот примерно так звучит ваше предположение ```Зачем носить с собой маленький чемодан? можно же таскать поезд с багажом```

Comment: Но поезд тяжело носить, а на скорость работы импорт никак не влияет

Comment: Ну так и вашему приложению будет "тяжело" таскать в себе все пакеты которые вы не используете :) (я не про скорость а про размер того что вы хотите впихнуть в приложение)

Comment: если вы рассматриваете сферического коня в вакууме, то такой подход имеет право на жизнь. но тогда нужно также допускать, что мы используем классы только этого пакета. в противном случае есть несколько проблем. во-первых, непонятно какой именно пакет импортировать. импортировать вообще все? тогда работать не будет вообще ничего, потому что именования классов в разных пакетах часто совпадает и нужно будет указывать всегда полное имя класса (пакет+класс), импорт теряет смысл. читаемость кода от этого ухудшается. не всегда очевидно по имени класса откуда он. итд.

Comment: а если вы конкретно про пакет утиля,  как самый часто используемый пакет, то да, в некоторых языках так их коробки и сделано.

Comment: Вы серьёзно вот это: «Самолет величиной с астероид средних размеров, со множеством навесных
украшений и финтифлюшек - при этом на его борт помещается только
несколько пассажиров. Стюарды суровы и величественны» предлагаете? Или это такой троллинг?

Comment: Удивительно, что никого не смущает сама необходимость писать треш вида `import ...`.

Answer (score 10):

Использование полных названий классов в импортах -- больше вопрос стиля, например в [Google Code Style §3.3](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3-import-statements) указано:

> **3.3.1 No wildcard imports**
> Wildcard imports, static or otherwise, are not used.

Основная причина для такого запрета -- избежать случайного импорта ненужных классов, что может приводить к нежелательным конфликтам названий классов из разных пакетов.  Наиболее яркий пример: при импорте `java.util.*;` возникнет коллизия между `java.util.Date` и его реально используемым наследником `java.sql.Date`.

Аналогичный вопрос на основном SO (2008 г.): [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/)

Что касается утверждения:

> *Ведь полный импорт занимает меньше памяти и функциональнее.*

Оператор импорта по сути является синтаксическим сахаром для сокращения полных имён классов, а не аналогом директивы препроцессора `#include` в С/С++.  Импорт всего пакета или одного конкретного класса *может* повлиять на время *компиляции*, но не на время исполнения (производительность) программы, так как сгенерированный байткод не будет отличаться.

Аналогичный вопрос на основном SO (2011 г.): [Performance difference between a wild card import and the required class import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128348/)

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос интересный, и я постараюсь ответить на него простым языком. Импортировать все классы из пакета допустимо лишь в том случае, когда из этого пакета используется очень много классов. Например, это выглядит не очень:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
```

Это даже не половина классов из `javax.swing`, но в данном случае будет лучше импортировать все классы:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

Если же вы используете не так много классов из пакета, пишите полные импорты.

В этом есть несколько преимуществ:

1. Другой программист поймёт, для чего именно этот импорт нужен.
2. Не будет никаких "сюрпризов" (про это уже говорил @NowhereMan, но я приведу свой пример):

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Timer timer = new Timer(); // Ошибка! Ссылка на класс Timer неоднозначна!
  }
}
```

Этот код не будет компилироваться, ведь есть как `java.util.Timer`, так и `javax.swing.Timer`.

В общем, в используйте полный импорт (за исключением случая с использованием большого количества классов).

Answer (score 3):

Если вы напишите `import java.lang.*;`  то увидите следующее:

> Remove this unnecessary import: java.lang classes are always implicitly imported.

Так как пакет `java.lang` подтягивается автоматически, неявно.
По аналогии, как все классы наследуются от `java.lang.Object`

Если вы напишите это:

```
public class UserEntity extends Object`
```

То увидите предупреждение:

> Class 'UserEntity' explicitly extends 'java.lang.Object'

Для работы приложения вы будете добавлять библиотеки(зависимости).
Вот для примера зависимости в простом приложении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот какие библиотеки проект подтягивает, даже половина на экран не влезла :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у вас во время написания кода возникнут конфликты. Вот я создал класс `User`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас спросят - какой из них надо добавить!??

`import` по имени, разрешает (устраняет) конфликт классов, то есть вы говорите `jvm`, какой именно класс вам нужен.
Вот для этого и нужен `import`, чтобы уточнить какой именно класс нужно использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Я лишь хочу добавить, что система пакетов в `Java` служит в качестве системы пространства имён.

Пространство имён - это некое хранилище множества имён *(в данном случае классов)*, которое необходимо для логической группировки некоторых сущностей, а также помогает отличать их от сущностей с таким же названием, но из другой группы сущностей.

Если бы в `Java` не было пространства имён *(пакетов)*, то пришлось бы для **каждого** класса придумывать уникальное название.

А импорт всего пакет по сути убивает смысл пространства имён, так как, как уже написали ранее, если в двух пакетах будут одинаковые классы, то мы не сможем их различить.