# Что не так с добавлением меню?

Tags: java

Вот код:

Класс main:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Menu;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        setTitle("Меню");

        setSize(640, 480);
        setResizable(false);

        Menu menu = new Menu();
        add(menu);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

menu красное. Error: Cannot resolve method 'add(java.awt.Menu)'

Попытался изменить на это:

```
add((PopupMenu) menu);
```

Но возникли новые ошибки:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.awt.Menu cannot be cast to class java.awt.PopupMenu (java.awt.Menu and java.awt.PopupMenu are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap') at com.company.Main.(Main.java:15) at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:22)

- Find why menu could be not null: add((PopupMenu) menu);
- at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:22) - new Main();

---

Класс Menu:

```
package com.company;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.Box;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JPanel {

    public boolean started = false;

    public Menu() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(280));

        JButton button = new JButton("START");
        button.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                start();
            }
        });

        add(button);

        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    }

    public void start() {
        removeAll();
        started = true;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (!started)
            g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(Menu.class.getResource("background.jpg")).getImage(), 0, 0, 640, 480, this);
        else
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    }
}
```

---

В классе Main я написал:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu();
add(menu);
```

вместо:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
add(menu);
```

Сейчас все Ok. Нет ошибок.

Но окно пустое. В нем нет картинки .. Почему?

Comment: Разобрался с CustomButton и ошибками в классе Menu. Но почему в классе Main в 'add(menu);'   появляется ошибка? menu красное. Error: Cannot resolve method 'add(java.awt.Menu)'

Answer (score 0):

Вы импортировали класс [`java.awt.Menu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Menu.html), а он НЕ является компонентом, который можно добавить к [контейнеру](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) или [компоненту](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html),см. документацию по методам:

- [`Container::add(Component component)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component))
- [`Component::add(PopupMenu popup)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#add(java.awt.PopupMenu))

Скорей всего, у вас просто перепутан import, так как ваше меню реализовано в пакете `com.company`.

Также импорт всего пакета `java.awt.*` в классе `Menu` может вызвать конфликт имён `java.awt.Menu` и `com.company.Menu`, как объясняется в ответе на вопрос: [Зачем усложнять импорт в джава?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476612/386633)

Лучше переименовать собственную реализацию, чтобы у неё было какое-то более уникальное имя, хотя бы `MyMenu`.